# How to validate same, repeated capital and lowercase character in a string?

Tags: c#, string, validation

I have two problems with this code (that I can see - ;^):

1) when if condition one is not met, both validation message boxes show; I only want one or the other to display given the conditions in each if block.

2) how can I validate (if block two) for the same uppercase and lowercase character in a string?

```
public partial class Substrings : Form
{
    public Substrings()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void buttonGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //validate input for 5 characters and same characters with Equals method
        if (textBox3.TextLength != 5)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The string must have exactly 5 characters, try again");
            textBox3.Clear();
            textBox3.Focus();
        }
        //validate only unique characters in string
        if (textBox3.Text.Distinct().Count() == 5)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox3.Text.Substring(0, 1)); //p
            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox3.Text.Substring(1, 1)); //o
            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox3.Text.Substring(2, 1)); //w
            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox3.Text.Substring(3, 1)); //e
            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox3.Text.Substring(4, 1)); //r
            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox3.Text.Substring(0, 2)); //Po
            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox3.Text.Substring(1, 2)); //ow
            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox3.Text.Substring(2, 2)); //we
            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox3.Text.Substring(3, 2)); //er
            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox3.Text.Substring(0, 3)); //Pow
            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox3.Text.Substring(1, 3)); //owe
            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox3.Text.Substring(2, 3)); //wer
            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox3.Text.Substring(0, 4)); //Powe
            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox3.Text.Substring(1, 4)); //ower
            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox3.Text.Substring(0, 5)); //Power
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("The string must have distinct, non-repeating characters");
    }
    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void buttonExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part, just use `else if` - then the second block will only be executed if the first block isn't.

For the second part you could use `ToLower` or `ToUpper` so you're comparing all characters in the same case.

So, combining these two changes:

```
else if (textBox3.Text.ToUpper().Distinct().Count() == 5)
```

Comment: It is much simpler to write `textBox3.Text.ToLower().Distinct().Count() == 5`

Comment: @Dusan it has the added advantage of actually working, too!  I think I've got brain fade.  You'd need an `IEqualityComparer<char>` here. I've changed my answer.

Comment: Also, the list box fill needs serious refactoring.

Comment: @Dusan I'll take any suggestions on refactoring too! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want to validate that the text box should not have more than 5 characters and then also validate that it needs to have unique characters. You can try this for it:

```
//validate input for 5 characters and same characters with Equals method
if (textBox3.Length != 5)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The string must have exactly 5 characters, try again");
    textBox3.Clear();
    textBox3.Focus();
}
//validate only unique characters in string
else if (textBox3.Text.ToLower().Distinct().Count() != textBox3.Text.Length)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The string must have distinct, non-repeating characters");
}
else
{
    // Do your stuffs here
}
```